# Jquery $('.class')[0].css returns undefined, editing single class element

Tags: jquery

When I attempt to access the css of one of my classes, it returns undefined. Currently $('.class') returns an array as it matches multiple elements, but I only want to edit the css of the first element (a div of this class). How can I edit the css of this specific div?

```
$('.pure-table')[0].css
undefined
$('.pure-table')[0]
<div class=​"pure-table">​…​</div>​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting elements by array notation, like this `[0]`, will return the DOM element, not jQuery object, use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
$('.pure-table').eq(0).css
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try

```
$( '.class:first' )
```